# ¿Cómo devolver el estado 401 en vez de 200 sin usar o invocar los métodos del Request o Response, desde el contenido del HTML/Razor?

Tags: html, c#, razor

Actualmente estoy haciendo una aplicación donde todas las vistas html se guardan en la base de datos, pero se renderizan con el motor de razor, por lo tanto he implementado un "Sistema de archivos Virtual" basado en el esquema:

```
    public sealed class DatabaseFileInfo : Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.IFileInfo
    {
...

public class DatabaseFileProvider : IFileProvider
    {
...
```

Esto, como es muy conocido, permite a grandes rasgos guadar una vista Razor/HTML en un Singleton binario basado en un Token que es consultado cuando se usa ina llamada **/View/....**

En el startp del projecto uso esta especificación para determinar cual será el manejador virtual de archivos de Vista (razor/HTML)

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

        services.AddMvc()
            .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();

        services.AddControllers(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);

        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation
            (options => options.FileProviders.Add(new DatabaseFileProvider()));

        services.AddSession();
```

La siguiente línea especifica cual será la clase que observa las llamadas a los endpoint/urls:

```
 services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation
            (options => options.FileProviders.Add(new DatabaseFileProvider()));
```

Es decir, DatabaseFileProvider es el prov. de archivos.

La pregunta es la siguiente; dado que no puedo usar las clases Request o response para establecer los headers, ¿de qué forma puedo en un cuerpo HTML/Razor ajustar el estado **401** en vez de **200** (Este es el estado por defecto cuando se devuelve lo que sea desde un Razor)?

**Notas** : Yo soy muy Open Source, pero por ahora no puedo publicar todo el código por un tema de privacidad, pero aseguro publicar el manejador de vistas más adelante en GIT.

Comment: pues antes de devolver la vista puedes hacer  return Unauthorized(); // Http status code 401. O si gustas agregar mas info puedes usar return StatusCode(MyObjetoRespuesta); Procura agregar tu pregunta al principio  el texto inicial es irrelevante para lo que necesitas.

Comment: Dado que la implementación es de tipo virtual, no es posible saber si la vista a retornar existe en la DB, por lo que no puedo predecir un error 401 o 404 ( pudo haber sido eliminada y debe retornar un 401 ) pero eso ya lo intenté pero debe ser algo dentro del razor o dentro de la implementación del plain-text del response html el cual es binario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es sencilla:

```
Response.StatusCode = 404;
```

Al hacer esto, se devuelve el StatusCode, código del estado del request lanzado.

Esto funcionó perfecto meses después...